# checking ttl for Rails.cache object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, time, ttl

So I have some items stored in Rails.cache and I always write them with :expires_in => 5.minutes

My question is, is there a way to see what the ttl is on a cache entry?

I know the entry class in activesupport has a method but I can't seem to get an entry object out of Rails.cache methods.

I'm implementing rate limiting by the way.

Comment: Don't take my word for it but I don't think there is a way. `expires_in` is parameter that gets stored internally in memcached and can't be taken out.

Comment: Yea I suspected that there was no way to get that, especially since it isn't available when using rails memory, thought I'd ask though just in case someone figured it out

Answer (score 2):

You can check ttl in Rails cache using command below.

```
Rails.cache.data.ttl("yourkey")
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases where your `Rails.cache` is a FileStore, and there is no `.data` to query, you need to reference the file that holds the item in question:

```rb
fpath = Rails.cache.send :key_file_path, "yourkey"
cache_entry = Marshal.load File.read fpath
expiration = Time.at cache_entry.expires_at
```

Answer (score 0):

This only applies if you're using redis_cache_store. If you are you can access the Redis connection and then call the ttl method.

```
Rails.cache.write("my_cache_key", "hello", expires_in: 100.seconds)
sleep 1
Rails.cache.redis.ttl("your_redis_namespace:my_cache_key") => 99
```